# Hiding a frozen field in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Can anyone help me out in hiding a frozen column in jqgrid 4.5.2 version.

I have a jqgrid with 4 frozen columns. I would like to hide 2 of them and show only two out of four frozen columns on the grid.

Note:: I have a show/hide button at the bottom of my grid to select these two columns and hide on the grid.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please include **always** in your question which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: Yeah @Oleg, it's jqGrid  4.5.2 is used in my project.

Comment: it's old and buggy. I recommend you to upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.2. You can use it from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: @Oleg: Is this possible to hide a frozen column in this version(i.e. 4.13.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible with old jqGrid 4.5.2, which you use and even with the latest 4.13.2 version of free jqGrid fork, which I develop.

I updated the code of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) to support hiding/showing frozen columns and reordering the column (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/da2eae0eb61cb040ddffb0c327da18d777aff45f)). The new option `notSkipFrozen: true` can be used in `showCol`, `hideCol`, `showHideCol` and `columnChooser` to force for it.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/columnChooserHideFrozen.htm) uses the latest code of free jqGrid from GitHub and it uses

```
$(this).jqGrid("columnChooser", { notSkipFrozen: true });
```

to call of `columnChooser` inside of `onClickButton` added by `navButtonAdd`. You can verify that one can hide/show frozen columns now or to move it's location. The new position of frozen columns will still stay inside of the first frozen columns of the grid. One can't move frozen column to non-frozen columns.